# Reloading a page every time it gets accessed

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is it possible to reload a page (like /home or /photos) every time the page gets accessed via the app-route element?

```
    <app-location route="{{route}}" url-space-regex="^[[rootPath]]">
    </app-location>
    <app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="[[rootPath]]:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-home name="home"></my-home>
      <my-discover name="discover"></my-discover>
      <my-pages name="pages"></my-pages>
      <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
    </iron-pages>
```

In my case I have used the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) and my web app contains several pages like /home and /discover that are all accessible via links in the drawer on the left side.

Right now the app however seems to keep the 'state' of a page or a menu was in even after I navigated to a different page within the app, like navigating to /discover from /home keeps the entire state of the page /home (scroll position, opened menus etc.) when I revisit the /home page.

I would like the app to freshly load a page every time the page gets accessed, so that it automatically discards the previous state the page was in. Is this possible with some onPageLoad in js or are there other options for the app-route element available?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use a server-side you can use socketio. And do ```on('connection', function() { reloadPage() })```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am planning to keep the routing client-side. I really just want the page to discard its state once it is loaded, and a reload seems to be the easiest way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there other options for the app-route element available?

Not sure but I think no.

By the way, that behavior comes from `iron-location` (included by `app-location`) as you can see in [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-location/blob/master/iron-location.html#L188). It just listen click event on body element so you can stop event propagation before it go to body.

For example (didn't test)

```
<dom-module>
  ...
    <a href='/discover' on-click='stopPropagation'>
  ...
    stopPropagation (event) {
      event.stopPropagation()
    }
  ...
</dom-module>
```